# How to plot route between two locations without using internet in c# for windows form application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created a windows form application that receives the data from gps module and according to that data it plot markers and route between them. This works online successfully. But I want to develop this functionality without using internet connection. Is this possible? The code I have uploaded works using internet.

```
private void route_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        double lat = Convert.ToDouble(lat1.Text);
        double log = Convert.ToDouble(log1.Text);

        double blat = Convert.ToDouble(baselat.Text);
        double blog = Convert.ToDouble(baselog.Text);

        PointLatLng point1 = new PointLatLng(lat, log);
        PointLatLng bpoint1 = new PointLatLng(blat, blog);

        MapRoute route=OpenCycleMapProvider.Instance.GetRoute(bpoint1, point1, false, false, 15);
        GMapRoute r = new GMapRoute(route.Points, "myroute")
        {
            Stroke=new Pen(Color.Red,5)
        };

        GMapOverlay routes = new GMapOverlay("routes");


        routes.Routes.Add(r);
        map.Overlays.Add(routes);

        dis.Text= route.Distance+"KM";

    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve"

Comment: Why do you use Graphics in windows application and create your drawings.. the another way can be the thirdparty diagram controls e.g. DevExpress Diagram

Comment: What does "route between them" mean? Are you asking how to write a Mapping application?

Comment: @NetMage actually route is between my current location and the location of my rocket . Same as mapping application but without internet.

Comment: What does "route between them" mean? Be explicit. For example, does it mean following roads? Does it mean straight lines across country? Does it mean walking paths and sidewalks but no cliffs?

Comment: @NetMage I am working on my sounding rocket so I am tracking my rocket's location so that I can find it when it lands on ground and my application will plot a route between my rocket's location and my location. On the launch site there is no internet available. so I have to do it without internet. Is it possible to do?

Comment: How do you expect the rocket to communicate its position to you?

Comment: @NetMage I am using Xbee for communication. One will be attached to the rocket and another one that is receiver will be connected to my laptop using arduino.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you really need is the bearing between your current point and your end point.

You can find the formula [here](https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

Formula:

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
where   φ1,λ1 is the start point, φ2,λ2 the end point (Δλ is the difference in longitude)
```

JavaScript: (all angles in radians)

```
var y = Math.sin(λ2-λ1) * Math.cos(φ2);
var x = Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2) -
        Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(φ2)*Math.cos(λ2-λ1);
var brng = Math.atan2(y, x).toDegrees();
```

Since `atan2` returns values in the range -π ... +π (that is, -180° ... +180°), to normalise the result to a compass bearing (in the range 0° ... 360°, with −ve values transformed into the range 180° ... 360°), convert to degrees and then use `(θ+360) % 360`, where % is (floating point) modulo.